# Elasticsearch: How many words occured once

Tags: elasticsearch

I am modifying my question to be a little more generic so please humor me...

Say I have a Elasticsearch index with each document holding a word from a textbook. Is there a way I can tell how many words occurred just once, how many twice, and so on?

ie the result is something like this:

```
# words occurring once       = 10,001, 
                  twice      = 503, 
                  thrice     = 807, 
                  four times = 997, 
                  five times = 23
```

Is there a way to do this in elastic?

I am not looking for "give me the top "x" words that occur most often" - that is easily retrieved by doing an aggregation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your documents have a field **word** that holds a word from the textbook. Your use case will be solved by using the **[terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)** bucketing that'll group all the occurrences of a word into one bucket. Thus your query would like this:

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "word_count" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "word" }
    }
}
}
```

With the following output:

```
{
"aggregations" : {
    "word_count" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
        "buckets" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "The",
                "doc_count" : 10
            },
            {
                "key" : "wild",
                "doc_count" : 2
            },
            {
                "key" : "fox",
                "doc_count" : 3
            },
        ]
    }
}
}
```

where doc_count indicates the occurrence of each word.

Comment: This just gives me the top occurrences of words: `["The" occurred 10 times, "wild" occurred 2 times, etc.]` If I have 10,000 words, I would have to get the full list and try to figure out the metric that I am trying to get. I am trying to get `[of the 10,000 words, 9900 show up once, 60 show up twice, 30 thrice and 10 four times]`